# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 376, 257, 1), found shape=(376, 257, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

I have 799 spectrograms:
[image]

and 799 labels:

[image]

and I want to create a tensorflow dataset from them.

I tried this :
[image]

but when i start training i get this error:

```
epochs=10

initial_history=model.fit(train_dataset ,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    verbose=1)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[39], line 3
      1 epochs=20
----> 3 initial_history=model.fit(train_dataset ,
      4                     epochs=epochs,
      5                     verbose=1)
.
.
.
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 376, 257, 1), found shape=(376, 257, 1)
```

What am I doing wrong?